# How to run a simple MongoDB java program from a unix terminal

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to execute a simple hello world program in `MongoDB`.

I have compiled my java file using

```
javac -classpath mongo-2.10.0.jar HelloWorld
```

what to do next. Should I create the jar for the classfile and execute or directly run the class file. I m new to `MongoDB`.

Comment: Whatever may be the DB..You can run a simple JDBC program directly with java command from command prompt or unix shell

Comment: I tried using java HelloWorld Its not working

Comment: Can you post the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. You can run it with:

   `java -cp mongo-2.10.0.jar:. HelloWorld`
2. Use `maven`  or `gradle` to build / run the project.
3. Create [one jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) out of your project files.

For simple testing, I would go with 1.